# RStudio regression table into beamer slide

Tags: tables, beamer, rstudio

I have a very basic Rstudio regression output table inputing in Latex issue. I get an error message pointing me to the end of the frame part, after the table and I can't see what's wrong. Here is the code I am using.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsthm,relsize}

\begin{document}
\title{Formative work2}   
\author{Antoine Zerbini} 
\date{\today} 

\frame{\titlepage} 

\frame{\frametitle{Table of contents}\tableofcontents} 


\section{Section no.1} 
\frame{\frametitle{Title} 
Each frame should have a title.
}
\subsection{Subsection no.1.1  }
\frame{ 
Without title somethink is missing. 
}


\section{Section no. 2} 
\subsection{Lists I}
\frame{\frametitle{unnumbered lists}

\begin{table}[!htbp] \centering 
  \caption{Results FX} 
  \label{} 

\begin{tabular}{@{\extracolsep{5pt}}lD{.}{.}{-3} D{.}{.}{-3} } 
\\[-1.8ex]\hline 
\hline \\[-1.8ex] 
 & \multicolumn{2}{c}{\textit{Dependent variable:}} \\ 
\cline{2-3} 
\\[-1.8ex] & \multicolumn{2}{c}{StudentSatisfaction} \\ 
\\[-1.8ex] & \multicolumn{1}{c}{(1)} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{(2)}\\ 
\hline \\[-1.8ex] 
 StudentStaffRatio & 0.413^{***} & 0.412^{***} \\ 
  & (0.061) & (0.061) \\ 
  & & \\ 
 controls.rank &  & -0.0003^{*} \\ 
  &  & (0.0002) \\ 
  & & \\ 
\hline \\[-1.8ex] 
Observations & \multicolumn{1}{c}{1,002} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{1,002} \\ 
R$^{2}$ & \multicolumn{1}{c}{0.048} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{0.051} \\ 
Adjusted R$^{2}$ & \multicolumn{1}{c}{-0.048} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{-0.046} \\ 
F Statistic & \multicolumn{1}{c}{45.943$^{***}$ (df = 1; 909)} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{24.388$^{***}$ (df = 2; 908)} \\ 
\hline 
\hline \\[-1.8ex] 
\textit{Note:}  & \multicolumn{2}{r}{$^{*}$p$<$0.1; $^{**}$p$<$0.05; $^{***}$p$<$0.01} \\ 
\end{tabular} 
\end{table} }

\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! May it be that you just removed some style files from the file produced by RStudio?

Comment: Thank you @marmot! I don't think so. I copy pasted the output from stargazer. I could have added the first 3 lines of comments starting by % but that makes no difference

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The source of your problem is a missing `\usepackage{dcolumn}`.

**Some other comments:**

- you don't need `graphicx` with beamer
- `\author{}`, `\title{}` etc. should, if possible, be used before `\begin{document}`
- better use `\begin{frame}...\end{frame}` instead of `\frame{}`
- defining an empty `\label{}` does not make sense
- your table has lots of empty lines and manual spaces, instead of these hacks use the `booktabs` package to get better spacing in your table.
- with the default beamer font size, your table was too big for a single frame, I choose a smaller font size instead. Even better would be to change the layout of the table. The columns 2 and 3 are unnecessary wide because of the last row.
- because of the excessive use of `\multicolumn`, some of the minus sigs where typeset as -
- the rapid changing between math mode and text mode messed up the spacing for the equations in from the "note"
- I don't know much about the `dcolumn` package, but please check the used options for the alignment, it looks off. (personally I prefer the `siunitx` package to align numbers in columns, see [Formatting table with siunitx: problem with parentheses and signs](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/174876/36296) on how to align statistic tables)

> **Moral of the story:** automatically produced code is ugly and needs manual adjustments. Don't just use it as it is.

An attempt to clean the code up a bit (some of the `\multicolumn` are still unnecessary):

```
\documentclass{beamer}
%\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsthm,relsize}

\title{Formative work2}   
\author{Antoine Zerbini} 
\date{\today} 

\usepackage{dcolumn}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
  \frametitle{unnumbered lists}

  \begin{table}
    \centering 
    \caption{Results FX} 
    %  \label{} 
    \small
    \begin{tabular}{@{}lD{.}{.}{-3} D{.}{.}{-3}@{}} 
      \toprule
      & \multicolumn{2}{c}{\textit{Dependent variable:}}\\
      \cmidrule{2-3}
      & \multicolumn{2}{c}{StudentSatisfaction}\\
      & \multicolumn{1}{c}{(1)} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{(2)}\\ 
      \midrule
      StudentStaffRatio & 0.413^{***} & 0.412^{***} \\ 
      & (0.061) & (0.061) \\ \addlinespace
      controls.rank &  & -0.0003^{*} \\ 
      &  & (0.0002) \\ 
      \midrule
      Observations & \multicolumn{1}{c}{1,002} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{1,002} \\
      R$^{2}$ & 0.048 & 0.051 \\
      Adjusted R$^{2}$ & -0.048 & -0.046 \\ 
      F Statistic & \multicolumn{1}{c}{45.943$^{***}$ (df = 1; 909)} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{24.388$^{***}$ (df = 2; 908)} \\ 
      \bottomrule
      \textit{Note:}  & \multicolumn{2}{r}{$^{*}p<0.1$; $^{**}p<0.05$; $^{***}p<0.01$} \\ 
\end{tabular} 
\end{table}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Many thanks for the answer and the detailed comments @samcarter!

Comment: @unisateur You're welcome!