# Aligning entries of a table at dots if entry is a number, otherwise centered

Tags: tables, columns

I have the following table, where the entries are either numbers **or** a dash, possibly followed by one or more asterixes:

```
\documentclass[notitlepage]{article}

\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
\centering

\begin{tabular}{lrrrrrr}
\toprule
& \multicolumn{2}{c}{(1)} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{(2)} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{(3)} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{(4)}\\
& Description &  & Description &  & Description & Description \\
\midrule
VarA &    1.123$^{**}$  & (1.123)  & 9.765$^{***}$ & (-22.123) & -3.321 & -4.123 \\
VarB &  -32.123$^{*}$   & (12.321) & 4.654         & (3.321)   &  6.321 &  4.123 \\
VarC &   &  & --$^{**}$ & (12.898) & -- & -- \\
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

I'd like to align the entries such that all numbers are aligned wrt. the dots. As the dashes don't have any dots to align after, they should just be center-aligned wrt. the column. Is that possible to do?

Comment: Take a look at https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/133714/172926

Answer (score 2):

Using an adapted version of [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/418315/134144) you can achieve the following alignment with the help of the `siunitx` package:

[image]

```
\documentclass[notitlepage]{article}

\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\usepackage{siunitx}
\sisetup{
    detect-all,
    table-align-text-pre     = false,
    table-align-text-post    = false,
    input-signs              = + -,
    input-symbols            = {*} {**} {***},
    input-open-uncertainty   = ,
    input-close-uncertainty  = ,
}
\begin{document}

\begin{table}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{l
                S[table-format=-2.3,table-space-text-post = {$^{**}$}]
                S[table-format=2.3,table-space-text-pre={*}, table-space-text-post={-*}]
                S[table-format=-1.3,table-space-text-post = {$^{***}$}]
                S[table-format=-2.3,,table-space-text-pre={*}, table-space-text-post={-*}]
                S[table-format=-1.3]
                S[table-format=-1.3]
                }
\toprule
& \multicolumn{2}{c}{(1)} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{(2)} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{(3)} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{(4)}\\
& {Description} &  & {Description} &  & {Description} & {Description} \\
\midrule
VarA &    1.123$^{**}$  & (1.123)  & 9.765$^{***}$ & (-22.123) & -3.321 & -4.123 \\
VarB &  -32.123$^{*}$   & (12.321) & 4.654         & (3.321)   &  6.321 &  4.123 \\
VarC &   &  & {--$^{**}$} & (12.898) & {--} & {--} \\
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Please note that the above shown table is wider than the textwidth of `article`.

---

Regarding the requested alignment of asterisks: Here is a suggestion using two columns (one for right aligned for the number and one left aligned of the asterisks) and the `makecell` package (to align the -- with respect to the center of the numbers).

[image]

```
\documentclass[notitlepage]{article}

\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\usepackage{makecell}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\sisetup{
    detect-all,
    table-align-text-pre     = false,
    table-align-text-post    = false,
    input-signs              = + -,
    input-symbols            = {*} {**} {***},
    input-open-uncertainty   = ,
    input-close-uncertainty  = ,
}
\begin{document}

\begin{table}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{l
                S[table-format=-2.3,table-space-text-post = {$^{**}$}]
                S[table-format=2.3,table-space-text-pre={*}, table-space-text-post={-*}]
                S[table-format=-1.3,table-alignment=right]@{}
                @{}l
                S[table-format=-2.3,,table-space-text-pre={*}, table-space-text-post={-*}]
                S[table-format=-1.3]
                S[table-format=-1.3]
                }
\toprule
& \multicolumn{2}{c}{(1)} & \multicolumn{3}{c}{(2)} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{(3)} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{(4)}\\
& {Description} & &  \multicolumn{2}{c}{Description}  & & {Description}  & {Description} \\
\midrule
VarA &    1.123$^{**}$  & (1.123)  & 9.765 & $^{***}$ & (-22.123) & -3.321 & -4.123 \\
VarB &  -32.123$^{*}$   & (12.321) & 4.654 &          & (3.321)   &  6.321 &  4.123 \\
VarC &                  &          & {\makecell[cc]{--}}  & $^{**}$  & (12.898)  & {--}   & {--} \\
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks, that is a good example. I know I asked for center-alignment of the dashes, but is it possible to align the left-most asterix of the dashes with the left-most asterix of the number?

Comment: @N08: If `--` would be a number, switching `table-align-text-post` from `false` to `true` would give you the desired alignment, but since `{--}` is text, you might be better off using a separate column for the asteriks. For an MWE  applying this suggestion, please see my updated answer.

Comment: Thanks, this is what I want. But is it possible to generalize the example such that dashes with asterixes can be written in all columns and be aligned with numeric entries? Right now it is only the 4th column that supports this (?)

Comment: @N08: You can of course use the same approach for all columns if you replace the column specifier of the respective column(s) by `S[table-format=-x.y.,table-alignment=right]@{}
                @{}l` with `x.y` being the corresponding value for the column. You will also have to add some `&` and add/adjust some multicolumn commands in order to have the entries in the right columns.